# Delete line in join table in "Many-to-many" unidirectional relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have two entities : Site and Language in a "Many-to-many" relationship in which Site is the owner side :

Site entity :

```
class Site
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Language", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="site_language")
     */
    protected $languages;

    /**
     * Initialisation
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->languages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getLanguages()
    {
        return $this->languages;
    }

    public function setLanguages($languages)
    {
        $this->languages = $languages;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->languages->removeElement($language);
    }
}
```

and nothing about Site entity in Language entity because as I said before, Site is the owner in this unidirectional relation.

So Doctrine has generated a join table, "site_language" with "site_id" and "language_id" as columns.

But I have an issue when I delete a Site.

Logically, when a Site is deleted, it should only delete in the join table the line corresponding to the "site_id" and the "language_id" of this Site.

**Example :** I have a Site which has the id "10". This Site has 2 languages, FR(id =1) and EN(id=2). So in the join table "site_language", there are 2 lines :

*site_id* || *language_id*

10      || 1

10      || 2

So when I want to delete this Site, it should delete this 2 lines in this table.
But I don't succeed. I only succeeded in delete the language in "language" table, but this is not good...

This is my deleteAction in the Site controller :

```
public function deleteSiteAction($siteId, Request $request)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $site = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('BackBundle:Site')
            ->find($siteId);

        if (!$site) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Site entity.');
        }

        $originalLanguage = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($site->getLanguages() as $language) {
            $originalLanguage->add($language);
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($siteId);
        $deleteForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($deleteForm->isValid()) {
            foreach($originalLanguage as $language) {
                if($site->getLanguages()->contains($language) == true) {
                    $site->removeLanguage($language);
                   // $entityManager->remove($language); -> **if I keep this line it delete the language in the "language" table**
                }
            }

            $entityManager->remove($site);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Le site a été supprimé');

        } else {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Une erreur est intervenue lors de la suppression');
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('site_list'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution : I have to flush my entity before delete my Site object

In my deleteAction :

```
[...]

foreach($allLanguage as $language) {
    $site->removeLanguage($language);
}

$entityManager->flush();

$entityManager->remove($site);
$entityManager->flush();
```